# Cannot Save File to directory using FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I won't break out or show the lengthy code in actually building the PDF itself because I know the file generation is working fine.

When I try the following:

```
$pdf->Output('abc.pdf', 'F');
```

I receive error:

> FPDF error: Unable to create output
>   file: abc.pdf

By changing the Output destination to 'D' or 'I':

```
$pdf->Output('abc.pdf', 'D');
```

The user is prompted to download the pdf that was generated and is done so successfully (views fine). The error makes me think it is a permissions error but fpdf should have access to write a pdf file to the directory the action is already occurring in correct?

Anybody dealt with this before?

Comment: Is the directory you're trying to write into writable by PHP? They aren't necessarily by default.

Comment: FPDF doesn`t have to have write permision, can have only read to execute. Review your permissions.

Comment: @Szymon: OP is not executing fpdf, just using it, and trying to write out a PDF file generated with FDPF. As such the script DOES have to have write permissions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your PHP script is executed from a web-page *(served by Apache, it is)*, then this code will be executed by the Apache *(sometimes called `www-data`)* user.

So, your Apache user needs to be able to write to the directory you're trying to write to.

Typically, you might have to give the `write` privilege to the `other` users of your system, using something like this from a command-line :

```
chmod o+w your_directory
```

The software you're using to upload your source files, if doing so using a GUI, should allow you to do that with a couple of chekboxes -- you need to check the "write" checkbox for the "others" users.

Comment: I am using a very basic FTP uploader currently so this is not available. I assume you are speaking of changing the fpdf.php file to use 'write' privileges?

Comment: No. I'm speaking about setting the write permission on the directory your script is trying to write to.

Answer (score 2):

`chmod o+w your_directory` fixed it for me :)